# MIME type error when trying to open my bootstrap template with Heroku

Tags: javascript, css, express, server, static

I am creating a portfolio using a bootstrap template however when I try to open it using heroku I get this error for all my css: Refused to apply style from '' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

It seems to be an error with the express server but I'm not sure what... when I try to view the css though the error I should see the code however it states 'Cannot GET'

I am using a mac and trying to run on google chrome and have tried to open with safari instead but still the same problem.

// This is my server.js code //

```
var express = require('express');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/css/main.css'));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/lib'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/lib/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/lib/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/lib/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/lib/hover/hover.min.css'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/lib/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css'));


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
});


app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Listening on Port ' + port);
});
```

// This is my header where the css is referenced and also my file layout //

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOGK6.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have encountered this problem before, if any of your CSS files begin with comments try removing them. I have noticed that sometimes it sees them as something other than CSS and will not load the CSS file(s).

Worked for me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a callback function to `express.static` so it can set the `Content-Type` header

```
var express = require('express');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var app = express();

function optionHeaders(){
  return {
        setHeaders: function (res, path, stat) {
             var extenstions = path.split('.');
             res.set('Content-Type', 'text/' + extenstions[extenstions.length -1]);
        }
  }
}
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist',optionHeaders()));    
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/lib',optionHeaders()));        
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
});        
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Listening on Port ' + port);
});
```

Read more about in the expressjs documentation - https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#setHeaders